# Matching elements in two PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating a search filter for an array of subjects. Basically, I am trying to compare two arrays.

```
$filtered_subjects = ["math", "science", "english"]
```

I am comparing this with the subjects that teachers' teach. Basically if every member of array filtered_subjects exists in a teacher's array, AND, that teacher's array contains no other subjects, it should be flagged and removed.

So for the following teachers:

```
$bob_subjects = ["math"]
$sam_subjects = ["math", "science", "english", "astronomy"]
```

Bob should be removed,
Sam should stay.

Any ideas on how I could best accomplish this with PHP? How can I compare the two arrays and get either YES or NO for whether the teacher should be removed?

One way I considered would be to do something like the following:

```
$result = array_diff($filtered_subjects, $sam_subjects);
if in_array($result, $filtered_subjects)
{
    // remove teacher
} else if in_array($result, $sam_subjects)
{
    // don't remove teacher
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_intersect`

```
$filtered_subjects = ["math", "science", "english"];
$sam_subjects = ["math", "science", "english", "astronomy"]
if (sizeof(array_intersect($filtered_subjects, $sam_subjects)) == sizeof($filtered_subjects)) {
    // it's your teacher
} else {
    // else
}
```